# Triple boot Windows 7, Ubuntu, and Elementary OS Luna

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, dual-boot, elementary

I want to try Elementary OS using a real installation (not via a VM). I currently have a dual boot set-up already with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Is it possible to do so? If so, please help me with some guidelines. Thank you.

Comment: Just continue installation, elementary luna is based on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you will need to do nothing
just install **elementaryos** just like you installed **ubuntu** and it will detect both windows and ubuntu and add them to the bootloader menu

If it didn't

- use ubuntu life cd
- open a terminal
- `sudo update-grub2`